# Do "visited" dialogue options in Mass Effect: Andromeda ever change?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

ME:A has a very nice UX improvement over the previous ME games: dialogue options which you have already read are a different shade. This is very helpful, since I have wasted a lot of time in the previous games redoing dialogue because I couldn't remember from the blurb whether I'd already used it. For example, (4) here is an as-yet-unvisited option, whereas (1), (3), (7) and (9) have been done:

[image: borrowed from https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/305236/146718]

However, this brings up a new problem: it's possible that a given dialogue option may result in a different dialogue further down the storyline. Does such a case exist? If yes, does the dialogue option change back to the "unread" display?

Comment: ..."I like you."?

Comment: ME:A blurbs oscillate wildly between being more amusing than the dialogue and being rather bland. :/

Answer (score 6):

Probably not.

Based on my 100 or so hours in the game, where I selected many dialogue options two and on occasion three times, sometimes on purpose but mostly by accident, I don't recall ever getting a different conversation.

I also don't recall ever seeing a previously grayed out option turn back to white, however they will sometimes be replaced with a new option in the same location.

Answer (score 5):

While maybe not a full answer, there are a few times that you can ask Kallo the same dialog option about the crew. He will go through every crew member, and if memory serves, the dialog option stays white. Once Kallo is out of crew members to gossip about, he will say something along the lines of "if I say any more, I might get in trouble!"

Comment: Yes, this is also true of the other similar choices (Cora with commando experience, Drack with war tales, and SAM with humour while it lasts).